# Using Swift 5.1 Property Wrapper seems to break SwiftUI updates. Known issue?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here's a head-scratcher: implementing a simple wrapper on an ObservableObject property negates SwiftUI updates.

The purpose of the property wrapper is to provide a getter / setter to UserDefaults. The property wrapper works fine. But it stifles SwiftUI updates.

Things I've tried:

-Adding @Published wrapper in addition to my custom wrapper. But Swift at the moment doesn't support composable wrappers (e.g. more than one property wrapper at a time).

-Manually adding a PassthoughSubject publisher, to replicate @Published functionality.

The latter also doesn't fix view updates on property value change.

The only workaround I've found is to abandon property wrappers. I end up having to set state in two places, 1) on the @Published property, and 2) in UserDefaults. This seems clunky, and anti-pattern of duplicating state.

Is this a known-issue?

Full compiling code is at https://github.com/taskcruncher/propertyWrapperSwiftUIBug.git. The 'works' branch is where I've had to duplicate state. The 'broken' branch is below, where using a custom property wrapper breaks SwiftUI updates.

**ContentView.swift**

```
import Combine
//https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/property-wrappers/

@propertyWrapper
struct PersistInUserDefaults<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: T

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}


class AppleUser: ObservableObject {

    static var shared = AppleUser()

    let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

    @PersistInUserDefaults(key: "appleID", defaultValue: "") var appleID: String {willSet {

        subject.send(newValue) // problem here: does not trigger UI updates 
        }}
}


struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var appleUser: AppleUser

    var body: some View {

        return VStack {
            Text(appleUser.appleID)

        }.onAppear{

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                         self.appleUser.appleID = "Sven" 
                     }


            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.5) {
                self.appleUser.appleID = "Olaf"
            }//update not reflected in UI

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.5) {
                          self.appleUser.appleID = "Anna"
                      }//update not reflected in UI

        }
    }

}
```

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let contentView = ContentView(appleUser: AppleUser.shared)

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo may need to separate @publish and @persist properties in two different region. 
Although composible property wrapper is not supported now, the chain of them still works in most time.

```
                    @propertyWrapper
            struct PersistInUserDefaults<T> {
                let key: String
                let defaultValue: T

                var wrappedValue: T {
                    get {
                        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
                    }
                    set {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
                    }
                }
            }

            struct PersistInUserDefaults_Wrapper {
              @PersistInUserDefaults(key: "appleID", defaultValue: "") var value
            }

            class AppleUser: ObservableObject {
                static var shared = AppleUser()
                @Published var appleID = PersistInUserDefaults_Wrapper()
            }

            struct ContentMMMMSSSView: View {

                @ObservedObject var appleUser: AppleUser

                var body: some View {

                    return VStack {
                        Text(appleUser.appleID.value)

                    }.onAppear{

                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                            self.appleUser.appleID.value = "Leonard"
                                 }


                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.5) {
                            self.appleUser.appleID.value = "Bill"
                        }//

                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.5) {
                            self.appleUser.appleID.value  = ""
                                  }

                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for taking the time to respond. In your opinion, is the ui-non-updates, even with a PassthroughSubject set, a bug, unimplemented functionality, or programmer error? (If a bug, I'll file a report.)

Comment: I think we may not get the correct use of the subject now.